# How can a Class B network be in the 10.0.0.0 space?

Tags: ipv4, vpc

I'm taking an AWS Lab to better familiarize myself with creating a VPC.

The instructions describe the example network we are to create in the lab like so:

[image]

My background is in software, not networking, so the second paragraph sent me on a hunt to refresh my networking knowledge so that I can understand more clearly what I'm creating and how it works.

I stumbled upon this excellent [video on TCP/IP addressing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WX5GaH5ootc) and it states that **10.0.0.0** is a Class A network which has a default subnet mask of **255.0.0.0**, but the lab I'm taking says:

> The VPS itself is a Class B network in the 10.0.0.0 space...[with a
>   subnet] of 255.255.0.0.

So what gives? How is the VPC a Class B network but it is in a Class A space (10.0.0.0)?

Comment: keep reading/studying. Any time you see anything about "classful" networking, you're still decades in history. Learn CIDR and ignore classful; also ask why you're bother to be shown classful. This may also help, [CIDR](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation) also, all homework/study questions are off-topic here...

Comment: It's free Amazon labs for learning AWS systems ... not actual homework / study questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add one footnote to @RonMaupin's answer: although classful routing is long dead, many people informally use the terms "Class A, B and C" as shorthand for subnet masks.   So when someone calls a network a Class A network, they simply mean it has a mask of /8 or 255.0.0.0.  Similarly, when they call something a Class B or Class C network, they merely mean it has a mask of /16 or /24, respectively.  That is the sense it is used in the quote you posted.

Comment: The server guys at work drive me crazy with that. They often insist on a "Class C" network. I try to explains what they are asking for, but they won't listen and tell me that they really do know what a Class C network is and absolutely must have a Class C network, So I get one for them, but then they aren't happy because it isn't in the Class A address space. Then I get a lecture from the server guy who asked for it explaining to me that any network with a mask of `255.255.255.0` is a Class C network, and I go through my explanation again, but I get told I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I feel the same way, but I got tired of pushing that rock up the hill ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First, classful routing has been dead for 20 years, replaced by CIDR and VLSM in 1995, and is really only useful as a historical reference.

The class of an address is determined by the first bits of the address. Some people mistakenly have decided that any `/8` is a Class A, any `/16` is a Class B, and any `/24` is a Class C. It's true those are the default network sizes for those classes, but that doesn't mean that `10.0.0.0/16` is a Class B network.

- Class A addresses start with `0` as the first bit.
- Class B addresses start with `10` as the first two bits.
- Class C addresses start with `110` as the first three bits.
- Class D addresses start with `1110` as the first four bits.
- Class E addresses start with `1111` as the first four bits.