# assign IP address

Tags: ip

I have network address with two routers as shown in the picture
if the address 12.12.12.1 is reserved as network address and 12.12.12.3 for the broadcast, how can I give the two routers interfaces addresses? 
there is only one address available which is 12.12.12.2
[image]

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome on this Stack Exchange. You made a small mistake in your IP subnet calculation. In `12.12.12.0/30`, the `12.12.12.0` address is the network address, `12.12.12.1` and `12.12.12.2` are assignable to the routers and `12.12.12.3` is the broadcast address.

Please see [this question and its answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation) for a more detailed explanation on IP subnet calculation.

Comment: thank you , I will , but isn't this address in the picture the network address ?
I didn't write  it by my self , it is already in the question topology

Comment: A /30 always has 2 usable addresses. I guess .1 was shown in the picture since that's the IP address of the interface of one of those routers.