# Additional subnets in a class C IP

Tags: subnet, ip-address, networking

If i'm designing a new subnet mask for a class C IP that will have 5 subnets that means I need to borrow 3 digits since 2^3-2 > 5. My question is, how many additional subnets do we have?

would it be 2^3-2 = 6 --> 6-5 = 1 additional subnet

or

would it be 2^3 = 8 --> 8-5 = 3 additional subnets

Comment: classfull addressing is dead for 27 years, forget about it. Also sorry but homework questions are off-topic here.

Comment: But for reference you can read [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3873/16930)  or [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/16930)

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the commercial Internet) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes.

Comment: I see now, ill make sure to keep homework questions out of here but it was interesting to see that im learning dead content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 6 usable host in /29 (255.255.255.248) subnet (borrowing 3 bits) would be required.

2^3 - 2 = 8 - 2 = 6

PS: Even we can use First IP (Network IP) is some systems too